# Masking CodeIgniter subfolder install with internationalized url

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have the a html/shtml website installed at the root of my public_html folder and a CodeIgniter install in the "ci_code" subfolder and two .htaccess files: one in the root folder and one the "ci_code" folder.

To access the CodeIgniter, website, I use the following url:
example.com/ci/{params}

I would like to mask to CodeIgniter folder name with internationalized url like these
example.com/ci_spanish/{params}
example.com/ci_english/{params}

How can I do this?

---

Root (/) .htaccess files

```
RewriteBase /

AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .html
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
Options +Indexes +Includes
```

---

CodeIgniter .htaccess file

```
RewriteBase /ci/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/application/views/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/application/modules/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /system/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /application/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^ci(.*)/(.*) /ci/$2
```

will turn a URL like

```
http://example.com/ci_engish/test
```

into

```
http://example.com/ci/test
```

However, then there is no way that I can see to tell CI which language you are going after. You could also do something like

```
RewriteRule ^ci_(.*)/(.*) /ci/$1/$2
```

which will turn a URL like

```
http://example.com/ci_engish/test
```

into

```
http://example.com/ci/english/test
```

from which you could use routes or some other mechanism to deal with the language.

http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ are nice little utilities to test `.htaccess` stuff